# Powershell Specify Minimum Search Depth

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

This question has actually come up for me a couple of times, and despite searching, I haven't been able to find an answer for it. I'm posting here because I've found a working solution that will hopefully help other users, but I'd also like to know if there is a better way to achieve the same result. When we write

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse
```

We are able to specify a *maximum depth*, and in that case, Powershell will only search subdirectories until that maximum depth. However, I sometimes want to search to at least a minimum depth. For my own purposes, I really just want to exclude the folder that I am searching in.

For example, if I am in `C:/MyFolder`, I want to get files from *subfolders* of `MyFolder`, but I do not want to get any file that is in `MyFolder` and not one of its subdirectories. So for the command

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```

Retrieving the following files would be **good**

> C:\MyFolder\test\hello.txt
> C:\MyFolder\abc\cde\goodbye.txt

and these would be **bad**

> C:\MyFolder\yes.txt
> C:\MyFolder\no.txt

To solve this issue, I can write:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Directory.FullName -ne $(Get-Location)}
```

Which I'm actually quite happy with, but I was wondering if there is a better way to search at a minimum depth, as I am a PowerShell novice. Obviously, we could write a function to handle this depth but I am wondering if any of the more experienced users have a better way of doing this.

Comment: There's a `-Depth` parameter. So, `Get-ChildItem -Path C:\MyFolder -Depth 2` will only search 2 directories deep.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala `-Depth` seems to specify maximum depth, not minimum

Comment: Its not a switch, its a parameter looking for an argument. So you need to specify the depth.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can *chain* two [`Get-ChildItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem) calls:

```
Get-ChildItem -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```

To generalize the solution, use a wildcard-based *path*; e.g., for a minimum depth of `3`:

```
Get-ChildItem */* -Directory | Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Filter *.txt
```